# Manipulating image by touch : IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web

I want to make a simple html page with just a single image on it. Then make this image become pinchable. 
I want to rotate it and zoom it in and out.
It may snap back to its original position when I release it.

i need code snippets that don't use any existing Javascript libraries for this – no jQuery, no Zepto, etc... it only needs to work in webkit-based browsers, but it MUST work on iOS.

Any recommandation or Key words that could be helpful to start with are appreciated.

Comment: @vico, the requirement is not to use any javascript libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to figure out how to program the pinches yourself, but touches are a standard HTML5 thing now. See here for info on getting the touches information:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/